# Help me for write this matrix

Tags: matrices

I want to write the attached determinant in latex but I can't. Can someone help me ?
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Please note, that this is not a do-it-for-me site. So you should [show, what you've already tried](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). This would increase your chance to get an answer. Otherwise it could happen, that the question will be closed.

Comment: As @Cabohah says "this is not a do it form me site". Please give us a MWE that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

with nicematrix

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
    \[
    D_n = \,
    \begin{vNiceMatrix}[
        xdots/shorten-start=12pt,
        xdots/shorten-end=5pt,
        columns-width=5mm,
        cell-space-limits=3pt
        ]
        a & \raisebox{-6pt}{$\mathbf{0}$} & b \\ 
        \hspace*{12pt}\mathbf{0} & \phantom{0} & \mathbf{0}\hspace{12pt}{} \\
        b & \raisebox{6pt}{$\mathbf{0}$} & a \\
        \CodeAfter
        \line{1-1}{2-2}
        \line{1-3}{2-2}
        \line{3-1}{2-2}
        \line{3-3}{2-2}
    \end{vNiceMatrix}_{[2n]}.
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,mathdots}
\usepackage{bm}


\begin{document}
\[
D_n=\begin{vmatrix}
    a   &   &   & & b\\
    & \ddots &\raisebox{1.2ex}{$\bm{0}$} &\iddots &  \\
    &  \bm{0} &   & \bm{0} &  \\
    & \iddots &   \bm{0} & \ddots &  \\
    b       &   &  &  & a
\end{vmatrix}_{[2n]}.\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Denoting determinants with bars is really old-fashioned (and ambiguous). Anyway, you can do it by decreasing the interline spacing at the appropriate spots.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathdots}


\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
D_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
a &&&&&&& b \\[-1.5ex]
&&& \mathbf{0} \\[-2ex]
&& \ddots &&& \iddots \\[-1.5ex]
& \mathbf{0} &&&&& \mathbf{0} \\[-2.5ex]
&& \iddots &&& \ddots &  \\[-1.5ex]
&&& \mathbf{0} \\[-1.5ex]
b &&&&&&& a
\end{vmatrix}_{\raisebox{0.5ex}{$\scriptstyle[2n]$}}.
\]

\end{document}
```

Not that the notation suggests too much, I'm afraid. I haven't the slightest idea of what it should mean.

[image]